# Any faster way to calcuate the number of strings in a istringstream

Tags: c++, string, counter

I am trying to check if a line has exactly 10 words. The way I did it, is I make a copy of the line, and extract one by one and increment the counter, if it is 10, I manipulate the line. But I feel like this is extremely inefficient since I have to do this for every line and most of lines are 10 words. So I am looking for a more efficient way to do this.

```
    while(getline(ifs, line)){
        istringstream iss (line);
        int s_counter = 0;
        istringstream iss_copy = iss;   //create a copy to test if there are 10 strings in a iss
        string s;
        while (iss_copy >> s){
            ++s_counter;
        }
        if (s_counter == 10){
            while(iss>>word){   
                ...//manipuate each word                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could just count space in line?

Comment: I don't think that feelings should be taken into account while considering if code should be optimized..

Comment: @billz I thought about it, but isn't that essentially the same idea?

Comment: @HoKy22 I mean this: http://ideone.com/tOfybI, you save istringstream operations

Comment: @billz Good idea, but the actual line looks like this: 
AH Ks Js AD Ac 6c 10s 9H  8s  7H //blah blah blah.. I only actually about the part before //

Comment: @HoKy22 do you mean it stops counting when it sees `//`?

Comment: @billz yup, it stops when it sees //, but it could be 9 strings before //

Comment: @HoKy22 These feelings: `But I feel like...`

Comment: Will the words always be separated by spaces?

Comment: @sbooth Yes, the line looks like: AH Ks Js AD Ac 6c 10s 9H 8s 7H //blah blah blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I man do this way:

```
int main()
{
  std::string s1("hi hi hi hi //blah");
  size_t pos = s1.find('/');  
  std::cout << std::count(s1.begin(), s1.begin()+pos, ' ') << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

OR

```
int countSpace(const std::string& s)
{
  int count = 0;

   for(size_t i=0; i<s.size()-1; i++)
   {
     if (s[i] == ' ')
     {
       count++;
     }
     if (s[i+1] == '/')
     {
       return count;
     }
   }
   return count;
}


int main()
{
  std::string s1("hi hi hi hi //blah");
  countSpace(s1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the STL algorithm way.. is it supposed to be faster than the other way you provided?

Comment: maybe STL one is slower, because it does twice find.

Answer (score 0):

You could use STL Algorithm more efficiently .

```
template<typename charT>
struct CntSpaceFunctor {
    bool isEnd ;
    std::size_t value ;
    CntSpaceFunctor( ) : isEnd(false),value(0) {} 

    inline void operator()( charT ch ) const {
         if( ch == charT(' ') && !isEnd)  ++value ;
         else if( ch == charT('/') )      isEnd = true ;
         else ;
    }
};
int countSpace( const string& str ) {
    CntSpaceFunctor<char> result ;
    return for_each( str.begin() , str.end() , result ).value ;
}
```